# Mocking the return value on pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to mock the return value of pandas apply function, and cannot seem to get it to work.

I am trying to create a mock return object (in this case my function returns a dict) and then have that return from the function I am calling in pandas.apply. I put that value in the @patch decorator of my unit test, but it still ends up calling the real function

```py
def pandas_function():
    data = {'one thing': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},'second thing': {0: 0.1, 1: 0.2, 2: 1.0, 3: 2.0}}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    val = df.apply(real_function, axis=1)
    return val

def real_function(row):
    return dict("foo": row['one thing'])
```

```py
Unit test class:
def stub_foo():
    foo="test"
    return dict("foo":foo)


Unit test class:
@patch('package.module.real_function',return_value=stub_foo())
def pandas_test(self, stub_foo)
    expected = pd.Series(data={0: {'foo': "test"}, 1: {'foo': "test"}, 2: {'foo': "test"}, 3: {'foo': "test"}})
    real = class.pandas_function()
    assert_series_equal(expected, real)
```

Response when running test:

```
AssertionError: Series are different

Series values are different (100.0 %)
[left]:  [{'foo': 'test'}, {'foo': 'test'}, {'foo': 'test'}, {'foo': 'test'}]
[right]: [{'foo': 1.0}, {'foo': 2.0}, {'foo': 3.0}, {'foo': 4.0}]
```

How do I get unittest to mock the response object from the apply function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things here, as bamdan suggests first fix the syntax errors:

```
def real_function(row):
    return {'foo': row['one thing']}

def stub_foo():
    return {'foo':'test'}
```

Next, I can replicate your error if I import `real_function` incorrectly. Assuming your `real_function` is defined in `functions.py`, you should import it like this:

```
import functions
```

See documentation on this here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

And then a complete example is:

Contents of `functions.py`:

```
def real_function(row):
    return {'foo': row['one thing']}
```

Contents of `test_pandas_function.py`:

```
import pandas as pd
from mock import patch

import functions

def pandas_function():
    data = {'one thing': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},'second thing': {0: 0.1, 1: 0.2, 2: 1.0, 3: 2.0}}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    val = df.apply(functions.real_function, axis=1)
    return val

def stub_foo():
    return {'foo':'test'}

@patch('functions.real_function', return_value=stub_foo(), autospec=True)
def test_pandas(my_mock):
    expected = pd.Series(data={0: {'foo': "test"}, 1: {'foo': "test"}, 2: {'foo': "test"}, 3: {'foo': "test"}})
    real = pandas_function()
    pd.testing.assert_series_equal(expected, real)
```

Note that I suggest also setting the `autospec=True` flag in your patch, you should read up on this.

Finally, my example here is just for a standalone test. If your test is part of a class you will need to adjust the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real function contains an error. At least it does when I try to run.

[image: Error description]

You should do instead

```
return {"foo": row['one thing']}
```

Hope that helps.